# Missing artifact error in Maven

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, pom.xml

I get a missing artifact error during Maven build because one of the dependencies declares it's parent artifact using a property for the version. Now the property itself is declared in the parent pom and my project's build fails giving this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project abc: Unable to get dependency
information for xyz:pqr:jar:SNAPSHOT: Failed to process POM for 
xyz:pqr:jar:SNAPSHOT: Non-resolvable parent POM xyz:pqr-parent:${someversion}
for xyz:pqr:${someversion}: Failed to resolve POM for 
xyz:pqr-parent:${someversion} due to Missing:
----------
1) xyz:pqr-parent:pom:${someversion}
----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
xyz:pqr-parent:pom:${someversion}
```

I have verified that the artifacts are present in correct location in the repository.

Is there a way to specify the value of `someversion` property used in the dependency pom?
If not, how should the dependency pom be changed to resolve the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a missing artifact error during Maven build because one of the dependencies declares it's parent artifact using a property for the version. Now the property itself is declared in the parent pom and my project's build fails giving this error (...)

This is a chicken and egg problem: you can't get the version of the parent to use from the parent.

> Is there a way to specify the value of someversion property used in the dependency pom?

AFAIK, this is not possible, properties in project.parent.version do NOT get substituted. You might want to check [MNG-624](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624) (and vote for it) and related issues.

> If not, how should the dependency pom be changed to resolve the error?

Use an "hard-coded" version in project.parent.version.