# Eliminate Maven POM redundancy

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a parent POM with the following config

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Each child project which inherits from this parent POM, has a config such as the following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.amadeus.jcp.ui.skinning.skinning-system</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I want all these project version numbers to stay in synch. At the moment, if I change the parent version to 1.3, I then have to go change all the child project versions to 1.3. Is there any way I can avoid duplicating the version numbers in all the child projects?

I tried replacing the above with

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.amadeus.jcp.ui.skinning.skinning-system</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

and

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.amadeus.jcp.ui.skinning.skinning-system</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</parent>
```

But neither of these work. I'm using Maven version 2.1.0.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried replacing the above with (...) and (...) but neither of these work. I'm using Maven version 2.1.0.

Not possible. With Maven 2.x, you must declare the `parent` element in child module and the `parent` element must include a hard-coded `version` (you can't omit it and you can't use a property, see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943553/missing-artifact-error-in-maven) and [MNG-624](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624)).

However, Maven 3.1 will supports **versionless parent elements** (see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it/3166762#3166762)).

Meanwhile, some plugin can make the maintenance a bit easier like the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) or the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and its [`versions:set`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) or [`versions:update-child-modules`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-child-modules-mojo.html) goals.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I guess I'll just have to wait until my company upgrades to Maven 3.1, though it's likely the sun will burn out before that happens.

Comment: @Don You're welcome. `versions:set` is a decent workaround until the sun EOL :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define a version... in the child module, but you have to give that in the parent definition...

```
+--- root
      +--- pom.xml (Parent)
      +--- module1
             +-- pom.xml (child 1)
```

You should also define a relativePath in your childs as well...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</version>
</parent>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
```

If you done so you should never change the version number by hand in your parent...let the release plugin do the work it will change the version entries in all childs (parents) appropietaley...if you really need to change things sometimes use the [maven-version-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the relativePath defaults to `../pom.xml` so adding this won't make any difference

Comment: I don't have a version defined in the child module, I just have a reference to the version of the parent module that the child depends on. The latter is what I'm trying to eliminate, because it will always be whatever the current version of the parent module is.

Comment: "But it makes things clearer to understand"

True, but at the cost of extra configuration. In this case I'm willing to trade a little less clarity for a little less config, YMMV.

Comment: Ah...seemed to be a misunderstanding...The version in parent area is necessary. There is no possibility to remove that. If you need to change use the release plugin or the version plugin.