# How to get classes of one project in classpath of another project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two java projects in eclipse, P1 and P2. P1 is the main project and P2 is subordinate to P1. After project compilation, I need classes of P2 in classpath of P1. How can I achive this?

Comment: You want the child class to be involved inside the parent class?

Comment: Yes classes of child project in the same location as that of parent project.

Comment: Are you using any Build tool for building your applications ? As example making parent-child projects is possible with maven. You can refer to [SO-Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209119/creating-multi-module-maven-projects-in-eclipse).

Comment: After compilation, you can do that. Before compilation I think you can move the code through the directories! :)

Comment: It is also possible without maven. You just have to add project here :Project>Properties>Java Build Path > Projects.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can make add project P2 to the classpath of P1 by rightclicking on the project P1 in the Package Explorer view. Then choose Build Path->Configure Build Path and in the second tab ('Projects') add project P2.